What's the grammatical role of the '(seemingly) object of passive sentences'?
I understand how passive voice can't have objects, but I keep seeing the sentences like this.

He was denied permission to do so.

Here, "was denied" is clearly passive voice. Then what's the grammatical role of "permission" here?

In conventional-grammar terms, permission (or actually the noun phrase permission to do so) is the direct object. Compare the active version

She denied him permission to do so

to a very similar

She denied him food and water.

In the latter, him is clearly the indirect object and the noun phrase food and water is the direct object.

Deny is ditransitive here and hence takes two objects, him and permission. The active-voice form of the sentence could be
Someone denied him permission to do so.
The direct object permission remains there in the passive-voice sentence.

He was denied permission to do so.

M+W in its sense 3b for deny has a similar example

was denied a refund

deny
